# Browser cannot resize to 320 and below on Mac with Selenium and java automation

Tags: java, selenium, browser, responsive-design

I have developed a test to test the responsiveness of the header image.
but it seems the browser windows of chrome and firefox cannot automatically resize to 320px width and below. Manually the browsers can only resize on windows OS. Any idea why this is happening and if there is a way to make the browser to resize automatically below 320px?

Here is the code although it does not seems like a code problem:

```
Resizing methods:
 public void resizeToMobileView(String phone){
        if(phone.equalsIgnoreCase(responsive_mobile_iphoneSmall)) resizeWindow(319,568);
        else if(phone.equalsIgnoreCase(responsive_mobile_iphone)) resizeWindow(320,568);
        else if(phone.equalsIgnoreCase(responsive_mobile_galaxy)) resizeWindow(400,900);
    }
```

A method for getting the src on the page object:

```
public void checkFotoSizeLarge(){
        String src3 = header_BackgroundImage().getAttribute("src");
        webPageHelper.verifyActualAndExpectedResults(src3, LargeHeaderPhoto,"Footer menu text verification", LargeHeaderPhoto.equals(src3));

    }
```

and the test suite itself:

```
 @Test(groups = "ResponsiveImage")
/* Checking image size on <320px */
    public void ImageSizeSmallCheckMin(){
        String screen_size = responsive_mobile_iphoneSmall;
        resizeToMobileView(screen_size);
        sleep(5);
        responsiveimage.checkFotoSizeSmall();
    }
```

Thanks!
AT

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a solution for Mac, but it is working on a virtual win OS machine though takes time to set it all up.